# How to import translated strings having dynamic variables?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

**Short:** How can I import .po file having dynamic variables in strings like follows

```
$message = t('Hi @firstname, please follow @sitelink or mail me at @email ', $var);
```

**Indetail:**

I've written a custom module to send mail notification to users. In that module `$message` string has dynamic variables like follows (sample)

```
$var = array('@firstname' => $username, '@sitelink' => $GLOBALS['base_url'], @email => $email);  
$message = t('Hi @firstname, please follow @sitelink or mail me at @email ', $var);
```

How can I import `$message` string to my site.

I could translate all the static strings to Spanish of other custom modules like follows.

```
#: mycustom.module
msgid "Are you sure to approve"
msgstr "¿estás seguro de aprobar"
```

But how can I write the same for Dynamic variables. Right now Spanish Users are getting their mail in English?

Note: I'm just using Drupal core *Locale* module.

Comment: Which is kinda sad because it's such a well written question :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two way to achieve this

Add string in a your .po file like follows

```
msgid "Hi @firstname, please follow @sitelink or mail me at @email"
msgstr "Hola @firstname, por favor, siga @sitelink o envía un email al @email"
```

and import that .po file by going

> Administration » Configuration » Regional and language » Translate interface » Import

[image]
 If you want to change individual translated strings go to

> Home » Administration » Configuration » Regional and language »
>   Translate interface » Translate

You can find list of strings there each having edit link beside. So you change the individuals like follows.

[image]

Hope this helps someone.